# How can make restful api in angular.js web application

Tags: angular

How can create restful api in angularjs cryptocurrency wallet application as coinbase to accept payment this cryptocurrency

Comment: You can't create restful apis in angular js

Answer (score 1):

Angular is front-end technology and you cannot create REST APIs with it (rather consume them). You can use any server side technology like - Java, PHP, NodeJS, etc. to develop REST APIs and consume them with AngularJS application.